# How to inform user their entered value is incorrect in CupertinoAlertDialog

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I have a Cupertino Dialog where I want the user to enter a valid email address before continuing and Im trying to figure out the cleanest possible way to do this:

Here is my code so far I have added in stars the place I want to provide input feedback to the user:

```
  Future showEmailAlertBox(
      Service serv, DateTime date, Duration dur, var price) async {
    await showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (context) {
          return CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: Text('Enter Email Address to confirm'),
            content: CupertinoTextField(
              controller: emailController,
            ),
            actions: <CupertinoDialogAction>[
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                isDefaultAction: true,
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (emailController.text.isNotEmpty &&
                      emailController.text.contains('@')) {
                    //Creating booking as the Email is confirmed
                    await dbhandler.createBooking(
                        pickeddate,
                        selectedTimeSlot,
                        selectedDurationOption!.duration,
                        selectedService!.title,
                        price);

                    await getAllBookings();
                    setState(() {
                      availableTimeSlots = getTimeSlots(
                          selectedDurationOption!.duration,
                          pickeddate!,
                          selectedService!);
                      selectedTimeSlot = ''; // Reset the selected time slot
                    });
                    _showConfettiAnimation();
                    // Close the current dialog
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  } else {
                    //**************** */
                    //Need to add some kind of feedback telling the user to enter a valid email address
                  }
                },
                child: const Text('Confirm'),
              ),
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                isDestructiveAction: true,
                onPressed: () {
                  decision = false;
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: const Text('Cancel'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
```

I am open to all suggestions as best practice is very important to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RegExp](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/RegExp-class.html) to check whether the given input is a valid email address:

```
RegExp emailRegExp = RegExp(r'^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+$');
```

Here is how your `CupertinoDialogAction` can look like:

```
CupertinoDialogAction(
  isDefaultAction: true,
  onPressed: () async {
    String email = emailController.text.trim();

    // Regular expression for a valid email address
    RegExp emailRegExp = RegExp(
      r'^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+$',
    );

    if (email.isNotEmpty && emailRegExp.hasMatch(email)) {
      await dbhandler.createBooking(
        pickeddate,
        selectedTimeSlot,
        selectedDurationOption!.duration,
        selectedService!.title,
        price,
      );

      await getAllBookings();
      setState(() {
        availableTimeSlots = getTimeSlots(
          selectedDurationOption!.duration,
          pickeddate!,
          selectedService!,
        );
        selectedTimeSlot = '';
      });
      _showConfettiAnimation();
      Navigator.pop(context);
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Please enter a valid email address.'),
        ),
      );
    }
  },
  child: const Text('Confirm'),
),
```

Comment: The snackBar doesn't really work because its hard to see as the CupertinoAlertDialog is over the screen